# php: getting value of php variable in foreach loop and passing it to a html "form-group" view

Tags: php, html

I am new to php and don't exactly know what I am doing yet. I got  a array of values that is passed from the controller of this view ($positions). I want to iterate through it and get each value in the array and then have the value show up in the html drop-down menu (form-group). I am trying to do this with the `echo` statement inside the loop, but it don't work, and I am kinda lost on how to do this.

```
<div id="middle">
<form action="sell.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" name="symbol">
                <option value=""> </option>

                    <?php
                    foreach ($positions as $position)
                    {
                    $symbol = $position["symbol"];
                    echo "<option value='APP'>$_POST["symbol"]</option>";  
                    //echo $_POST["symbol"];
                    //print $_POST["symbol"];

            //echo "<h1>Hello " . $_POST["symbol"] . "</h1>";
```

Comment: I can see hardly any sense in that code at all … you are setting the same `value` for every option and the same text for each option as well. And with the value you are assigning to `$symbol` you aren’t doing anything at all …

Comment: What exactly is a `$position`? A form option has a value (which is usually an id) and a description which goes between the tags.

Comment: I haven't finished the code yet, since i need to find out how to pass php variables into the echo statement first.

Comment: That's why I only touched on concatenation subject below

Comment: Brian: if you could update your answer on how I also pass $position[symbol]into the "value" of the form it would be great.

Comment: @AlanCook Do you know how the value would be populated into the form in pure HTML (i.e. without regards to PHP)?  If not, you need to look into that. If so, all you need to do is output the variable value into the same property using php via concatenation.

Comment: _“since i need to find out how to pass php variables into the echo statement first”_ – if something that basic is still a problem to you, then please go through some tutorials on the matter first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[String Concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) `.` allows combination of PHP variables (`$position`) with strings (`<option>`)

```
<?php

    foreach ($positions as $position) {                 
        echo "<option value='". $position["symbol"] ."'>" . $position["symbol"] . "</option>";
    }

?>
```

Anything within quotes is a string,  `"string" . $variable . "string"` concatenation is taking the value of the PHP variable and combining it with your strings.

Comment: What about the value? We need to figure out what he wants there. There's no point in all of the options having the same value.

Comment: Brobin: I want both values to be the same, but thanks Brian, your code answers my question perfectly, give him some upvotes for me! I got to low reputation :(

Comment: Happy to help Alan, stick with Stack Exchange, you're rep will be up there before you know it =) Good luck.